# Confused about trying to find the correct spherical co-ordinates for this tricky triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to change the limits of integration to spherical co-ordinates in this particular question. I was wondering if someone would kindly be able to assist me in figuring out what the limits should be after changing to spherical co-ordinates? I'm also really bad at visualing and drawing these things, so, I'm kind of stuck on this.

The integral to calculate is given as follows:

\begin{align}
\int^{2}_{0} \int^{\sqrt{4-b^2}}_{b} \int^{\sqrt{4-a^2-b^2}}_{0} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}\:dc\:da\:db.
\end{align}

Any help (and if possible if you could tell me the bounds so I can verify after I have applied the method of converting the coordinates that I have done so correctly) would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Helen.

**EDIT:** The bounds I came up with in the end were, $ 0 \leq r \leq 2$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$, $0 \leq \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ with the integral turning out to be $\pi$, is this correct can somebody verify? Thanks!

Comment: Can you identify what shape these (rectangular) limits define?

Comment: Appears to be some sort of sphere, cylinder and line (in the plane) bounding it.

Comment: Yes, the outermost integral bounds the region between $b = 0$ and $b = 2$, the middle integral between the plane $a = b$ and the (half-)cylinder $a \sqrt{4 - b^2}$ and the last between the plane $c = 0$ and the (hemi)sphere $c = \sqrt{4 - a^2 -b^2}$. What region do all of these bound? I often find it immensely useful to draw a picture to answer exactly this sort of question.

Comment: You've made a number of insignificant edits here. Every edit bumps the question on the front page and pushes other questions off it, so edits should only be made if they are substantial.

Comment: I haven't got any answers yet, so, I'm still stuck unfortunately. I've been trying to visualise it but I don't know each time I try if I'm getting the correct bounds